# Proof request:"Figure Reflection Theorem"

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

"Figure Reflection Theorem" states following:

> If a figure determined by certain points, then its reflection image is the corresponding figure determined by the images of those points.

I encountered the theorem on the page below, which attempts to show proof of "Kite Symmetry Theorem": http://proofsfromthebook.com/2015/04/15/kite-symmetry-theorem/

P.S. If you attempt to write a proof for "Figure Reflection Theorem" yourself, then please do **not** use triangle congruence theorems or SSS "postulate", as they are not yet proven.

Comment: That "theorem" rather seems to be a definition what a "reflection image" should be.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe But how can we be sure that if we reflect a figure, then we get the same figure as its reflection? Like that if we reflect the Egyptian triangle, we will get a triangle and it will be the Egyptian triangle specifically?

Comment: How is "reflected image" defined?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I think in the context of the linked page it probably means reflective symmetry

Comment: That cannot be a theorem, it's a definition. Moreover, in that supposed "proof", line $m$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AC$, not the angle bisector. And then, by which theorem do they know that $m$ contains $B$ and $D$?